# Help to send data from one list to another using temporary object type

Tags: apex, list

can someone help me with this operation with lists?
I have two lists, one is a custom object and the other is :

```
public class OppNegocioTemp {
    public Double Demanda_Compra {get;set;}
    public Double Oferta_Venda {get;set;}
    public String VariedadeNome {get;set;}
    public String idopp {get;set;}
    
    public OppNegocioTemp(Oportunidade_de_Negocios__c oppNeg){
        Demanda_Compra=oppNeg.Demanda_Compra__c;
        Oferta_Venda=oppNeg.Oferta_Venda__c;
        VariedadeNome=oppNeg.Variedade__r.Name;
        idopp=oppNeg.Id;
    }
}
```

I don't know the name given when creating this type of lists, what I did so far was to receive the data in a vfp and save it in this temporary list, and now I send the data from this temporary list to the object (save in the database)

```
Controller

public List<OppNegocioTemp>getOppNegocios(){
        if(oppNegocios==null){
            oppNegocios=[Select Id, Variedade__c,Variedade__r.Name, Oferta_Venda__c, LastModifiedDate, Licenciado__c, Safra__c,Demanda_Compra__c, Conta__c  
                         FROM Oportunidade_de_Negocios__c WHERE Licenciado__c =: idlicenciado AND Safra__c =: safraActual ORDER BY LastModifiedDate DESC ];
        }
        for(Oportunidade_de_Negocios__c i:oppNegocios ){
            listTempOppNegocios.add(new OppNegocioTemp(i) );
        }
        
        for(OppNegocioTemp i:listTempOppNegocios){
            oppNegocios.add(listTempOppNegocios(i));
        }
        
        return listTempOppNegocios;
    }
```

in short I did a select for popular `oppNegocios` then I sent the data from `oppNegocios` to `listTempOppNegocios` and now I want to do the opposite, send the data from `listTempOppNegocios` for `oppNegocios`
but I must be wrong in the syntax... I keep getting the following error:

```
 Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void listTempOppNegocios(OppNegocioTemp) from the type aSiteOppNegociosController
```

thank you who can help...

Comment: Full controller code (at least all bits relevant for this question) would be useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
...
        for(OppNegocioTemp i:listTempOppNegocios){
            oppNegocios.add(listTempOppNegocios(i));
        }
...
```

you need to have (notice that you need to call `get` on list to get an element or use array accessor `[]` notation instead of method call `()`  notation)

```
...
        for(OppNegocioTemp i:listTempOppNegocios){
            oppNegocios.add(listTempOppNegocios.get(i));
        }
...
```

With that said, you could also achieve what you are trying to as follows without you looping.

```
oppNegocios.addAll(listTempOppNegocios)
```